# Convert 12:00:00.000 always to 12AM issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datetime, converters

I had an issue like this. In my development environment, when I read the record from SQL Database: 12:00:00.000, the convertion always return 12PM in my application. But in the customer environment, it always return 12AM....and of course it's wrong

Have you ever faced this issue?

Thank & best regards,

Comment: maybe time zone issue?

Comment: Show your code here where you display time. Give us more informations..

Comment: I used my own framework to CRUD so cannot post all of them here. But you know that the code is really simple. Insert to DB -> 12:00:00.000 -> Read it -> 12PM -> Right but in the Customer environment -> Read it -> 12AM -> Wrong

Comment: I would say it's because of time settings on SQL Server

Comment: "and of course it's wrong"; why "of course"? who is to say whether 12 is 12am vs 12pm. Actually, *technically* the concept of 12am / 12pm is inherently wrong: neither makes sense. 12 noon and 12 midnight I could get behind :)

Comment: Which _time zones_ you and your customer use?

Comment: Timezone my customer used is UTC+1 (Copenhagen) and my timezone is UTC+7...I tried to change my timezone to Copenhagen but no luck, it shows right result

Comment: @MarcGravell: I said is wrong because, SQL save the datetime is 0-23:59:59 so 12 is must be 12PM...12AM = 0:00:00.000

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "12:00:00.000" is a `string`, consider converting it to a `DateTime` using the following method call:

```
string myValue = "12:00:00.000";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myValue, "HH:mm:ss:fff");
```

Using [HH as the hour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), a 24h date format is used.

Remember: this only works in the exact format specified in the input.

Comment: but why it is shown 12PM in my environment but 12AM in customer environment :( with the same app

Answer (score 1):

```
return DateTime.ParseExact("12:00:00.000", "HH:mm:ss:fff");
```

Comment: Actually, I have already known the solution to parse it correctly but the question here is: why it is wrong to convert in customer environment :(